# 500 Internal Server Error while inserting to Windows Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, azure-mobile-services

When using the following code modified from the Azure for Mobile Services website, I get a "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException was unhandledMessage: Internal Server Error  (500 InternalServerError - Details: {"code":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"})" error.

My code:

```
    private MobileServiceCollectionView<pin> Pins;
    private IMobileServiceTable<pin> pinTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<pin>();
    public class pin
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object content { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    private LiveConnectSession session;
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Authenticate()
    {
        //authentication code from the Azure site, I deleted it here to save space.
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    public long getTimestamp()
    {
        //Find unix timestamp (seconds since 01/01/1970)
        long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00").Ticks;
        ticks /= 10000000; //Convert windows ticks to seconds
        return ticks;
    }
    public async Task<bool> Refresh()
    {
        List<string> CategoriesMixed = new List<string>();
        Pins = pinTable.Where(pin => true).ToCollectionView();
        if (Pins.Count < 1)
        {
            pin pin = new pin();
            pin.category = "Welcome";
            pin.content = "Hello, World!";
            pin.name = "No Pins :(";
            pin.comments = string.Empty;
            pin.timestamp = getTimestamp();
            pin.type = "text";
            await pinTable.InsertAsync(pin);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (pin nowPin in Pins)
            {
                await pinTable.DeleteAsync(nowPin); //since I'm still trying to get the inserting pins thing to work, I'm having it delete all pins it finds for the user.
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await Authenticate();
        await Refresh();
    }
```

One thing that could be important is that I was able to insert one pin into the database, but after that this error is being thrown. Also, if I put a breakpoint at the if(Pins.Count < 1) line, it shows that Pins.Count is returning 0 when there is a pin in the database.

Also, in the Azure Management Portal, I have the following as my script for Insert (from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/authorize-users-in-scripts-dotnet/):

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
  item.userId = user.userId;    
  request.execute();
}
```

and my script for read:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
   query.where({ userId: user.userId });    
   request.execute();
}
```

The error is being thrown on the "await pinTable.InsertAsync(pin);" line within Refresh(). There are no error logs in my Azure management portal. If there's any other information you need, just ask :)

Update 1: I think my problem is related to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/thread/82ae07a1-5832-4dc9-97d7-1cda1fb33bc2, but that question is still unanswered.

Comment: Whenever you get a 500 InternalServerError at the client, you can go to the admin console of the Mobile Services in Azure and check the log for additional detail on the exception that was thrown at the server side. I know this was fixed, but this information may help others looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess below line is creating problem

```
Pins = pinTable.Where(pin => true).ToCollectionView();
```

`ToCollectionView();` always returns count as 0. This is the bug here. What do you think Josh Twist?

Stavros: I think below line can help your program to running smooth

```
List<Pin> Pins = await pinTable.Where(pin => true).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I ended up just redoing all my code and it worked :)

but I think this would've helped, so thanks :D